# show negative hours with time calculations?

Tags: python, datetime, python-datetime

is there a way to show negative hours?
for example:
if a user checksin and checksout and has 3 hours worked but he should have worked for atleast 4 hours the calculation (3 - 4) should result into -1 hour (-01:00).
but when i do this calculation:

```
checkin = datetime.datetime(1, 1, 1, 8) # this is 0001-01-01 08:00:00
checkout = datetime.datetime(1, 1, 1, 11) # 0001-01-01 11:00:00

should_work = datetime.timedelta(hours=4)
has_worked = checkout - checkin # results in 03:00:00

result = has_worked - should_work # this results into "-1 day, 23:00:00" insted of "-01:00"
```

is there some other library or datetime function for this kind of things?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `timedelta` object isn't that good at display formats. Minus 1 day, plus 23 hours **is** -1 hour, but that's awkward. Since there are lots of ways to display deltas, (e.g., should you allow 25 hours, or should that be a day?), its normal to do the math yourself. This one just does hours and minutes. multiple days are expressed in hours >= 24.

```
import datetime

def timedelta_str(td):
    s = int(td.total_seconds())
    if s < 0:
        s = abs(s)
        neg = "-"
    else:
        neg = ""
    m, seconds = divmod(s, 60)
    hours, minutes = divmod(m, 60)
    return f"{neg}{hours:02d}:{minutes:02d}"

checkin = datetime.datetime(1, 1, 1, 8) # this is 0001-01-01 08:00:00
checkout = datetime.datetime(1, 1, 1, 11) # 0001-01-01 11:00:00

should_work = datetime.timedelta(hours=4)
has_worked = checkout - checkin # results in 03:00:00
result = has_worked - should_work

print('result', timedelta_str(result))
```

Comment: wow amazing so counting with the seconds is the way to go for .. i have only one more question about the return of the function, what does the 02d in hours /minutes mean?

Comment: That's an f-string, where the stuff in {} references variables to be printed. The part after the colon is a format specification. It says to zero fill 2 digits. So, instead of 1 you get 01. This is all customizable. See the docs [Format string syntax]( https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax)